# Getting AVAudioPCMBuffer working (AVAudioFile.mm error code -50)

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, swift

I'm trying to set up a basic example in a Swift playground (code below) but have also tried it with Objective-C with the same result.

```
import AVFoundation

let fileURL = ... // have tried a wav file and a aiff file
let myAudioFile = AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL, error: nil)
let myAudioFormat = myAudioFile.fileFormat
let myAudioFrameCount = UInt32(myAudioFile.length)
var myAudioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: myAudioFormat, frameCapacity: myAudioFrameCount)
// have also tried a smaller frameCapacity
```

It works fine up to this point, but then terminates with this:

```
var myError: NSError?
myAudioFile.readIntoBuffer(myAudioBuffer, error:&myError)
```

I have also tried naming the argument with buffer:myAudioBuffer but that gives an "extraneous argument" error.

Ultimately, I want to get out raw PCM data from the buffer as a Swift array of floats.

Comment: I really don't see any problem with your code here; given that, can you show your code as well in Objective-C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AVAudioPCMBuffer`'s `PCMFormat` has to be set as the `AVAudioFile`'s `.processingFormat` and *not* its `.fileFormat`: I thought these were the same, but that's not the case!

Comment: I knew this! But I thought they were two types and that in your case you needed the fileFormat. Good, nonethless, that I did not just answer, because I was only 99% sure. Nice that it works for you now.

Comment: @Unheilig Thanks anyway :) I could have sworn I'd tried this already, but apparently not. The -50 error code/crash wasn't too helpful either! Unfortunately, now this is fixed, it's led to a new (Swift-related) problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090119/from-unsafepointerunsafepointercfloat-to-an-array-of-floats-in-swift