# From UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<CFloat>> to an array of floats in Swift?

Tags: avfoundation, swift

I'm trying to access `AVAudioPCMBuffer.floatChannelData` using Swift but it is of type  `UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<CFloat>>` (in Objective-C, `@property(nonatomic, readonly) float *const *floatChannelData`) and any attempt I make to access it results in execution failed.

Sample code to set-up a quick AVAudioPCMBuffer in a Swift Playground is included in a previous question:

[Getting AVAudioPCMBuffer working (AVAudioFile.mm error code -50)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088470/getting-avaudiopcmbuffer-working-avaudiofile-mm-error-code-50)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work?

```
let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: myAudioBuffer.floatChannelData, count: Int(myAudioBuffer.format.channelCount))
let floats = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: channels[0], count: Int(myAudioBuffer.frameLength))
```

Comment: Nope: I get a "fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
Playground execution failed: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)."

Comment: I get that error with the ``let channels = ...`` line. The ``Int(myAudioBuffer.format.channelCount)`` part evaluates correctly though.

Comment: Update: This works! Thank you for this. It causes a crash in a Swift Playground but does work in-app.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't give `samples` as an array of floats `Array<Float>`, but rather an `UnsafeArray<CFloat>`. Is it possible to get an `Array<Float>` from the `UnsafeArray<CFloat>` without iterating over the whole array and pulling out the individual floats?

Comment: @JamieBullock You can do ``let safeFloats: Float[] = Array(UnsafeArray(...))`` which seems to work.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks, that looks like a useful pattern. In the end I stayed with the UnsafeArray<CFloat> for my project. The call to an Array() seems to add a costly copy operation (for large arrays) and with the UnsafeArray<CFloat> I am able to access and set values without any problems. This is all a bit ugly though, hopefully we'll get some Swift audio API improvements in future releases.

Comment: With the latest version of swift, change `UnsafeArray` to `UnsafeBufferPointer` and `length:` to `count:`

Comment: **(Swift 3 Update) You can also directly index UnsafePointers:**
like: `audioBuffer.floatChannelData![0]`

Answer (score 4):

What you can also do is in order to access `AVAudioBuffer`:

```
for var i = 0; i < Int(audioBuffer.frameLength); i+=Int(audioMixerNode.outputFormatForBus(0).channelCount) {
    self.audioBuffer.floatChannelData.memory[i] = 0.0f; // or whatever
}
```

You can find more about that in the [Apple pre-release documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPCMBuffer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAudioPCMBuffer)

> The `floatChannelData` property returns pointers to the buffer’s audio
>   samples, if the buffer’s format is 32-bit float. It returns `nil` if it
>   is another format. The returned pointer is to `format.channelCount`
>   pointers to float. Each of these pointers is to `frameLength` valid
>   samples, which are spaced by `stride` samples.