# How to correctly initialize an UnsafePointer in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(font: CTFont?, glyph: CGGlyph, transform: CConstPointer<CGAffineTransform>)`:

```
let myFont = CTFontCreateWithName("Helvetica", 12, nil)
let myGlyph = CTFontGetGlyphWithName(myFont, "a")
let myTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
```

But how do I correctly pass `myTransform` to `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph`?

I've tried creating a `myTransformPointer` to pass to the function like so:

```
var myTransformPointer: UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform> = UnsafePointer().initialize(newvalue: myTransform)
```

but I get this error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:20:76: error: '()' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>'
var myTransformPointer: UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform> = UnsafePointer().initialize(newvalue: myTransform)
```

so then I tried explicitly naming the type:

```
var myTransformPointer: UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform> = UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>().initialize(newvalue: myTransform)
```

and then I get a different error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:20:95: error: could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments
var myTransformPointer: UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform> = UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>().initialize(newvalue: myTransform)
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The auto-complete suggests this should work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simplest solution is using `withUnsafePointer` function:

```
let myFont = CTFontCreateWithName("Helvetica", 12, nil)
let myGlyph = CTFontGetGlyphWithName(myFont, "a")
var myTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

var path = withUnsafePointer(&myTransform) { (pointer: UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>) -> (CGPath) in
    return CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(myFont, myGlyph, pointer)
}
```

The `initialize` is not a constructor. You would have to `alloc` a new memory using `UnsafePointer<T>.alloc`, then `initialize` and then `dealloc`. Function `withUnsafePointer` does that all for you.

Note that `myTransform` cannot be a constant (`var` not `let`) otherwise you cannot use it for an `inout` param (`&myTransform`).

Comment: I just tried this in a Playground and it doesn't give an error, but it gives ``path`` as a ``__NSCFType`` rather than the ``CGPath`` expected. Will test it in an app to see if it's a Playground issue. Thank you for the reply anyway! I saw the ``withUnsafePointer`` function in the documentation but I completely missed that it could be used to *create* the pointer too.

Comment: Yep; works in-app but not in a Playground. Perhaps this is an intended limitation of Playgrounds because I encountered a similar issue in another question (linked). If so, it'd be nice if the Playground threw an error instead of just giving ``__NSCFType`` which is a bit opaque... Thanks again for your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090119/from-unsafepointerunsafepointercfloat-to-an-array-of-floats-in-swift

Comment: @Matthew It's `__NSCFType` because there is no real runtime type for `CGPath`. Even in Obj-C you can't get the type of a `CGPath` because it's a C struct, not an Obj-C object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! And I confirm it does work in a Playground too. I had thought it wasn't because when I tried using the ``path`` to construct an ``NSBezierPath`` it wasn't working -- I assumed it wasn't because it showed ``__NSCFType`` instead of ``CGRect`` (which google suggested might be a memory-related bug), when it was actually just a syntax error on my part. Oops.