# Cannot convert value of type 'CMSampleTimingInfo' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<CMSampleTimingInfo>'

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

```
let duration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(self)
let timeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(self)
let decodeTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetDecodeTimeStamp(self)
let sampleTime = CMSampleTimingInfo(duration: duration, presentationTimeStamp: timeStamp, decodeTimeStamp: decodeTimeStamp)

let videoInfo: CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef?
CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer!, &videoInfo)

var oBuf: CMSampleBufferRef?
CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer!, true, nil, nil, videoInfo!, sampleTime, &oBuf)
```

`self` is an instance of CMSampleBufferRef.

The last line throws the build error: `Cannot convert value of type 'CMSampleTimingInfo' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<CMSampleTimingInfo>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach.. Using `var` for sampleTime

```
let duration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(self)
let timeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(self)
let decodeTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetDecodeTimeStamp(self)
var sampleTime = CMSampleTimingInfo(duration: duration, presentationTimeStamp: timeStamp, decodeTimeStamp: decodeTimeStamp)

var videoInfo: CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef? = nil
CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer!, &videoInfo)

var oBuf: CMSampleBufferRef?
CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer!, true, nil, nil, videoInfo!, &sampleTime, &oBuf)
```

I'll accept this as the answer because the syntax is cleaner than the `withUnsafePointer()` approach.  But the `withUnsafePointer` does also work, if you prefer to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're passing a `CMSampleTimingInfo` and the function calls for a `UnsafePointer<CMSampleTimingInfo>`. I have not tried it, but other SO answers ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110769/how-to-correctly-initialize-an-unsafepointer-in-swift)) seem to suggest something along the lines of:

```
withUnsafePointer(&sampleTime) {
    (unsafeSampleTime: UnsafePointer<CMSampleTimingInfo>) -> Void in
    CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer!, true, nil, nil, videoInfo!, unsafeSampleTime, &oBuf)
}
```

If you get over the problem with sampleTime, from the function's signature, it looks like you'll have the same problem with oBuf. In that case you will need `withUnsafeMutablePointer`.